# How to transpile and minify single file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a React application, and in my application I'm relying on `react-scripts`, so the build command is defined like this `"build": "react-scripts build"`, and it works all fine. Now, the point is that inside my `src` directory I have a JS file called `wrapper.js`, which is a standalone file, and it is pure JS, no React stuff, but it uses ES6 and some newer features. So, what I want to do is that, I want create a new command, which will transpile and minify this file and will create a standalone copy of it. I thought to use `webpack` and I created a `webpack.config.js` file in the root of my project, which looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + 'build',
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: 'wrapper.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'wrapper.js')
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MinifyPlugin()
  ]
};
```

And I added the following to my `package.json` file `"wrapper": "webpack"`. Now, when I run `npm run-scripts wrapper`, it executes the webpack command, but it throws error. The output looks like this:

```
> webpack

Hash: 0aa67383ec371b8b7cd1
Version: webpack 4.19.1
Time: 362ms
Built at: 04/06/2019 10:54:46 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = wrapper.js
[0] ./src/index.js 223 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 22:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <Root />,
|     document.getElementById('root'),
| );
```

What I see is that the problem is that `webpack` also tries to transpile and minify other files in my `src` directory, because it seems it has hit my React app's `index.js` file. How can I exclude everything? Or more precisely, how can I tell `webpack` to transpile and minify only the file `/src/wrapper.js`, and not to touch anything else at all?

Comment: `__dirname + 'build'` you need a directory separator in that path otherwise it will be like `'/your/projectbuild'` instead of `'/your/project/build'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `entry` object to your `webpack.config.js`.

```
module.exports={
    entry: './src/wrapper.js',
    ...
}
```

`webpack` points the `entry` object by default to `./src/index.js`.

So if you don't override `entry` object, `webpack` will bundle the file in `./src/index.js`

**Update**

To point to a `output` directory properly

```
output: {
    filename: 'wrapper.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
}
```

Comment: @terett i updated answer with your issue about `output`

Comment: Please check my edited code. I think the transpiling does not work properly. I get a new `wrapper.js` generated in build directory, but it seems very generic. I mean it does not include code from my original `wrapper.js` file, that one includes `addEventListener` and some other functions, but the generated output does not include them. Can you please check my edited code above?

Comment: @terett can you keep the entry value as i specified in the answer and test your code? if you have your project in github please share url

Comment: I tried with your entry too. I mean the problem is not the entry now, it recognizes the `wrapper.js` file that it is 7KB, but at the end it generates a 900bytes minified generic file, that does not include anything from my `wrapper.js` file.

Comment: @terett you have renamed your output bundle to embed.js . embed.js could have your latest js code

Comment: Okay, it seems there was a problem in my original file. Fixed it now.

Comment: if you have your project in github please share url to your code

Answer (score 5):

Lighter weight alternative could be to create a script in your package.json and use `babel-minify`, https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-minify

package.json

```
{
  ...

  "scripts": : {
    "minify": "minify wrapper.js --out-file wrapper.min.js --mangle.keepClassName"
  }

  ...
}
```